# Webscraping - Selenium BeautifulSoup - cycling through pageination

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Im trying to mess about with selenium a bit (just learning pieces - asked a few questions regarding beautifulsoup and have had some great advice.

Anyway, im just simply trying to cycle through the pages and grab the div.details and print how many it finds (as initial test).  Problem is it seems to just sit on the first page and reload it be stuck in the loop.

How would i change this so it cycles through page1, page2 then end?

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv
import pandas
from pandas import DataFrame
import re
import os
import locale
os.environ["PYTHONIOENCODING"] = "utf-8"


from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

page = 1

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
url="https://www.gunstar.co.uk/view-trader/global-rifle-snipersystems/58782?page={page}"





#grab all links which contain the href specifed

with requests.Session() as session:
  while True:
    res=session.get(url.format(page=page))
    soup=BeautifulSoup(res.content,'html.parser')
    gun_details = soup.select('div.details')
    if soup.select("nav_next") is None:
        break
    page += 1
    driver.get(url) #navigate to the page
print(len(gun_details))
```

Comment: I cannot run the code. You can do `print(url.format(page=page))` and try debug why this is happening.

Comment: seems to print the correct url each time, but isnt browsing to it and seems to just keep cycling ignoring the break? - the nav_next class is within the right arrow for browsing the pages.

Comment: Then you can print value of `soup.select("nav_select")` and can find something from there.

Comment: links show ?page=2 ?page=3 etc etc (there are only 2 pages within this particular dealers adverts) and the selenium webdriver doesnt browse to the new pages though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need selenium to navigate you can use request method to do.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv
import pandas
from pandas import DataFrame
import re
import os
import locale
os.environ["PYTHONIOENCODING"] = "utf-8"

page = 1
url="https://www.gunstar.co.uk/view-trader/global-rifle-snipersystems/58782?page={}"

with requests.Session() as session:
  while True:
    print(url.format(page))
    res=session.get(url.format(page))
    soup=BeautifulSoup(res.content,'html.parser')
    gun_details = soup.select('div.details')
    print(len(gun_details))
    if len(soup.select(".nav_next"))==0:
        break
    page += 1
```

I have provided to print and console it is showing.

```
https://www.gunstar.co.uk/view-trader/global-rifle-snipersystems/58782?page=1
10
https://www.gunstar.co.uk/view-trader/global-rifle-snipersystems/58782?page=2
4
```

Comment: This is what i had before going down the Selenium road.  Was wondering why was only printing out the 4 for the len(gun_details) - had it in the wrong place.

Comment: @AndrewGlass : There is only 4 elements available on that page.

Comment: Hi KenduK - just noticed was yourself again - thanks for the help there.  ~Just wondering - see if i change the print(len(gun_details) to print(gun_details) it prints all the gundetails - but cannot seem to be able to figure out how to grab all the links within the details.  ill update to show what im trying to do now

Comment: I appreciate that If you code post my answer and post a new question and your expected output.

Comment: I'll be back to the house in an hour.  ill stick it up shortly